# Compare entity's property( of type List of strings) to a filtering list of strings(keywords) inside IQueryable in EF Core5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linqkit

I am trying to write a Linq expression that takes an IQueryable data then filters it without having to use ToList() or ToEnumerable()  , as this will be handling a large load of data and we prefer that the filtering operations happen in DB.
The handled data is of type Article , and the filter am using is of type Filter :

```
public class Article
{
  public string title {get; set;}
  public List<string> Tags {get; set;}
}



public class Filter
{
  public List<string> keywords {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to filter the articles with their tags property containing any of the keywords brought in the filter .

Below is what I have tried so far ( but didn't work ; couldn't get translated to SQL ):

```
   IQueryable<Article> query = await GetQueryableAsync();
   query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Intersect(filter.keywords).Any());
   query = query.Where(x => filter.keywords.Any(y => x.Tags.Contains(y)));
   query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => filter.keywords.Contains(y)));
```

Also tried predicate builder from LinqKit , no success
Tried below code too :

```
    Expression<Func<Article, bool>> predicate = (Article) => false;
    foreach (var term in filter.keywords )
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Tags.Contains(term));
    query= query.Where(predicate);
```

Before delving into the expression trees, does someone have some other suggestions to try, or starting points to build an Expression tree for such purpose.Thanks

Comment: How Tags can be list of strings? How it os stored in database? Why GetQueryableAsync is async?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for your interest , yes we can store list of strings in sql  server and have entities with properties  of type List<string> in EF Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives) , per the second question , GetQueryableAsync is async in here cause that's the method calling dbContext.Set<Articles>, I am supposed to add a ToList at the end of the Linq expression (after doing the filtering) , so it will reach db to run sql  and bring data, for that it's async